# jQuery each(), process one by one after inner ajax comepletes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code

```
$("[input]").each(function(){
  var data = $(this).val();
  $.post('someurl.php',{data:data},function(result){
    alert(result);
  });
});
```

Now, when I open my network tab, post ajax requests seems to be started simultaneously, but I want to achieve one by one. That means when one ajax request completes, I want each() to wait to loop again.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: ajax stands for asynchronous only.

Comment: Just a reminder: the first **A** in AJAX stands for **Asynchronous**.

Answer (score 7):

It is because of the asynchronous nature of ajax, what you could try is something like

```
process($("[input]"));

function process($inputs) {
    if (!$inputs.length) {
        return;
    }

    var $input = $inputs.eq(0);
    var data = $input.val();

    $.post('someurl.php', {
        data: data
    }, function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }).always(function () {
        process($inputs.slice(1))
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cub19csv/)

Comment: What is difference with async false?

Comment: @Phoenix async false will block the browser... where as in this there are no blocking... as soon as a async request is completed a second one is send

Comment: I voted to delete my answer in favor of this one, which is a bit more elegant and does what OP wants when there are errors.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you put those `inputs` in a `form` and then use `$('form').serialize()` to send them all to the server at once...just in case **you wish to do it a little faster** and you want to **avoid repeated calls to the server**...

unless if you *REALLY* have to send them one by one, *then you could loop making several calls to the server* which could **SLOW** your system if you happen to have many `input` fields

Something like this makes a single call to the server:

```
<form>
<input name='input_1' />
.
...

...

...


...


...
<input name='input_1000' />

</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var myForm = $('form')

$.post(
      'someurl.php', //The link to your .php file with a $_POST

   {
        data: myForm.serialize() //Serialize the form with its 1000 input fields
    }, function (result) {

///Handle Errors and others here.

        console.log(result);
    })
```

Comment: that's actually the most sensible answer of all... but OP must have his reasons

Comment: Sure just incase he had no idea he could simply `serialize` them in a `form`... the suggestion could come in handy

Comment: Actually, sending all data will output data once at once. I need to output data for each request. If some error occurs at backend, it will be outputted without interrupting rest of the process. :)

Comment: If there is an Error, it will still be an error and some pending processes might still be interrupted... i.e: if the user was to enter a wrong `Email` Id format, you don't expect the `form` to jump that field and deliver others... what if out 10 important `field`s the user only enters 1 which is the last one... if you can't `catch` those Nine(9) before heading to the server, that might be a Dangerous and Huge BUG in your codes

Comment: No, what I mean is if some criteria is not matched, then you can output an alert message. My bad.

Comment: Ok, just in case you wish to do it a little **faster** and you want to **avoid repeated calls to the server** when you happen to have 100 or 1000 `input fields`, feel free to `serialize` a `form`. With this you work like a Pro and impress your friends!!